# Input/Output Error Copying Files from Internal Harddrive to External Drive. (Ubuntu running from Live CD)

Tags: hard-drive

I am attempting to transfer files from an internal hard drive to an external hard drive.

Both mount fine and I can view files in them. When I try to copy a few of the image files they fail and pass an input/output error. However other files work fine. The files are under 1 mb in size. The reason I am attempting to do this with a ubuntu live cd is that the windows no longer boots and trying to backup my files before I reformat.

What do I do now? Is there any non intrusive way to check to see if maybe the files are corrupt or if its maybe the cable.

Thanks, Jacob

Comment: How are connecting the external drive, and what is the partition type?

Comment: NTFS, Partition 1 only C:\ and USB 2.0 in the back of the case.

Comment: Use Disk Utility, to check the drive, and I would try a different USB cable.

Comment: I think its the internal drive, not the usb. USB works fine when I transfer other files off the harddrive, its only one folder that appears not to work.

Comment: Then use Disk Utility, to check the internal drive.

Comment: You can also run `fsck` on the partition that has problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can try command `ddrescue`, it may be able to work around the broken path. Beware though, that you will lose data.

Restoring from backup will be easier :)